# Find the Laplace transform of the following hard equation

Tags: laplace-transform

[image]

Ok so the objective is to factor this into something that resembles the Laplace tables. Give me some help pls. thx

Comment: Partial fractions. Then complete the square in the irreducible quadratic.

Comment: maybe not so hard

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Using  a little variant [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html),

$$\frac{4s+1}{s(2s^2+2s+1)}=\frac As+\frac{B\left(s+\dfrac12\right)+C}{2s^2+2s+1}$$

as $$\frac1{2s^2+2s+1}=\frac12\cdot\frac1{\left(s+\dfrac12\right)^2+\left(\dfrac12\right)^2}$$

Comment: The required formulae are available here (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaplaceTransform.html)